# what does the flag "-u" in a OPTIONS line of a sysconfig file mean in linux?

Tags: linux

what does the flag "-u" in a OPTIONS line of a sysconfig file mean in linux?

example -
in the file  `/etc/sysconfig/ntpd`:

`OPTIONS="-u ntp:ntp"`

Comment: which sysconfig file ?

Comment: Absolutely nothing.  You need to figure out where the -u is being used and look at the man page for that command to find out.  Here I suspect that would be `man ntpd`.  As for sysconfig, that's just a variable being set.

Comment: updated in question.  it's the ntpd file.  one of the many sysconfig files on the operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to guess that in this particular case it means `user` and that the `ntp:ntp` means user ntp and group ntp. I would though expect it to be application specific.

From the ntpd(8) man pages

```
   -u user[:group]
           Specify  a  user,  and  optionally  a group, to switch to. This
           option is only available if the OS supports running the  server
           without  full  root  privileges. Currently, this option is sup‐
           ported under  NetBSD  (configure  with  --enable-clockctl)  and
           Linux (configure with --enable-linuxcaps).
```

Comment: is it normal to have a ntp user to run this, is that a default system user?